# USB 3.0 hubs don't work with my motherboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, motherboard, usb-hub

I have a PC with a Gigabyte GA-P67A-D3-B3 motherboard, which has 2 USB 3.0 ports and some USB 2.0 ports. I would like to use more than 2 USB 3.0 devices, so I thought of using a USB 3.0 hub. I bought two of these: Unitek Y-3089 and a Sharkoon one (EAN: 4044951016976). Both of these produce the same error.

If I plug them into any USB 3.0 port on the computer, and I plug either my Sharkoon Drivelink Combo USB 3.0 (a HDD Rack) or my Samsung Galaxy S10+ into it, then Windows 7 (I know it's not supported anymore) shows a notification: Failed to install driver, and I cannot use them.

However, if I plug these devices directly into the same USB 3.0 port, they work perfectly.

Also if I plug any of these hubs into a USB 2.0 port, and either the HDD Rack or the Phone into it, it works (though slower).

Is it possible that a motherboard is incompatible with USB 3.0 hubs?

What can I do if I want to use at least 4 USB 3.0 devices but have only 2 ports?

**Update**

I bought a Delock 89281 PCIe USB 3.0 Card with three external and one internal ports: https://www.delock.com/produkte/G_89281/treiber.html?setLanguage=en

I installed the hardware and the software by running Setup.exe from the CD in the box.

My devices work on the new ports (I can read their contents, etc.), even if they are connected to this port through the hub.

However, at shutdown I always get a BSOD, see its details later.

I removed the card (the hardware) from the PC, and there is no more BSOD. Although my DVD-Drive and my Virtual Clone Drive have a yellow triangle with a black exclamation mark in Device Manager and their Properties says:

```
Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)
```

The details of the BSOD are always as follows (except for the exact value of memory addresses):

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Commander\Desktop\minidumps2\041520-24788-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*C:\Symbols
*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 7601.23915.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr.170913-0600
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`03605000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`03847750
Debug session time: Wed Apr 15 18:17:03.598 2020 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:05:54.362
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
...............................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
..............
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 50, {fffff88804594428, 0, fffff8800459180a, 5}

Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\AppleCharger.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for AppleCharger.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for AppleCharger.sys

Could not read faulting driver name
Probably caused by : AppleCharger.sys ( AppleCharger+280a )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

6: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff88804594428, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff8800459180a, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory
    address.
Arg4: 0000000000000005, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


Could not read faulting driver name

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff800038b1100
 fffff88804594428 

FAULTING_IP: 
AppleCharger+280a
fffff880`0459180a 498b14dc        mov     rdx,qword ptr [r12+rbx*8]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  5

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50

PROCESS_NAME:  wininit.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff880027b83c0 -- (.trap 0xfffff880027b83c0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=00000000ffffffff rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff88004592340
rdx=fffff88004594580 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8800459180a rsp=fffff880027b8550 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000001  r9=0000000000000004 r10=0000000000000001
r11=0000000000000001 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
AppleCharger+0x280a:
fffff880`0459180a 498b14dc        mov     rdx,qword ptr [r12+rbx*8] ds:91b0:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800036f10d1 to fffff80003675e00

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`027b8258 fffff800`036f10d1 : 00000000`00000050 fffff888`04594428 00000000`00000000 fffff880`027b83c0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`027b8260 fffff800`03673f2e : 00000000`00000000 fffff888`04594428 24700003`b2500100 00000000`ffffffff : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x3a421
fffff880`027b83c0 fffff880`0459180a : fffffa80`0c72e840 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0d61a1a0 fffff880`03ea76eb : nt!KiPageFault+0x16e
fffff880`027b8550 fffffa80`0c72e840 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0d61a1a0 fffff880`03ea76eb 00000000`00000000 : AppleCharger+0x280a
fffff880`027b8558 00000000`00000000 : fffffa80`0d61a1a0 fffff880`03ea76eb 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 : 0xfffffa80`0c72e840


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
AppleCharger+280a
fffff880`0459180a 498b14dc        mov     rdx,qword ptr [r12+rbx*8]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  AppleCharger+280a

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: AppleCharger

IMAGE_NAME:  AppleCharger.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d2ad809

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_AppleCharger+280a

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_AppleCharger+280a

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Any idea?

Comment: I can only suggest using a PCIe 4-port USB 3.0 expansion card. I would be wary of USB-anything-more-than-3.0 with Windows 7. I cannot guarantee it will work, but one from a reasonably good manufacturer like StarTech has a chance. If your PCIe slots are occupied/covered by other cards, that won't work. Drivers for that M/B are available for Windows 10 64-bit, if that's a viable path. P.S. try a different USB 3 cable from the PC to the hub, just in case that's the problem.

Comment: "Is it possible that a motherboard is incompatible with USB 3.0 hubs?" - No

Comment: Reinstall your Windows 7, and run proper Intel INF files and all drivers FROM MANUFACTURER's site. And forget your problem. And don't be too smart with various"bugchecks" etc.

Comment: Isn't it bothering you that the fault is associated with some module called "AppleCharger"? Apple is completely foreign to Windows. Try to remove everything associated with Apple on your PC, and try again.